# Cron: cli.php does not work in the latest Civicrm

Tags: cron, php8

This happens on Civicrm for Joomla. It prevents both upgrading to Php 8 and upgrading to latest Civicrm, as doing any of these stops the cron job.

This is what I see with Civicrm 5.49.3:

```
$ php74 domains/figg.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s figg.org -u cronjob -p DeveFarl0 -e Job -a execute
PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called statically in /home/usiako1s/domains/figg.org/public_html/plugins/authentication/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 305

$ php81 domains/figg.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php --help
PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /home/usiako1s/domains/figg.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php on line 265
```

Using the latest Civicrm, the first example (with php74) generates the string "Error", and I was not able to pinpoint where it fails (I don't speak Php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with `cli.php` and `cv` in 5.57.0 on Joomla.  That is fixed in 5.57.1 just released.

For php versions, see the notes at https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#php  You're probably better sticking with 7.4 for now.

Comment: I upgraded to 5.57.1 and I get these warnings:
WARNING: Class Civi\Api4\Event\Subscriber\ActivityPreCreationSubscriber was expected to have a service definition, but it did not. Perhaps it needs service name.
Same for classes:
 Civi\Api4\Event\Subscriber\ContributionPreSaveSubscriber was...
 Civi\Api4\Event\Subscriber\CustomGroupPreCreationSubscriber was ...
 Class Civi\Api4\Event\Subscriber\OptionValuePreCreationSubscriber was ...
PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called statically in .../civicrm.php on line 305

Comment: Are you on J4?  I don't think that's officially [supported](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#joomla) yet although work has gone into making it work.  Do log those warnings at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues

Comment: No, it's J3. I posted a bug report at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues/44